# Ajax keeps refreshing the entire page instead of just the comment section

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on a project with codeigniter and I decided to implement ajax into the comment section so that the whole page is not refreshed when the user submits his comment. The comment is displayed automatically but the page keeps getting refreshed. I don't know what I am doing wrong here but any help would be appreciated.

**MODEL:**

```
public function create_comments($post_id){
    $data = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'users_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
    );
    return $this->db->insert('comments',$data);
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function create($post_id){

    //checking if user is logged in
    if(!$this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')){
        redirect('users/login');
    }
    $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);        
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('body', 'Comment', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        $this->session->set_flashdata('comment_error', 'comment field is empty comment');
        redirect('posts/'.$slug,'refresh');

    } else {
        $this->comments_model->create_comments($post_id);
            redirect('posts/'.$slug);
        }
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('comments/create/'.$post['id'], 'id="comnt"'); ?>
    <div class="panel-footer">
    <!--//THIS IS THE FIELD WHICH COMMENTS WOULD BE ADDED-->
        <div class="">
            <input type="hidden" name="slug" value="<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>">
            <small class="text-center text-danger"><?php echo form_error('body'); ?></small>
            <div class="input-field">   
                <textarea id="icon_prefix2" name="body" class="materialize-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                <label for="icon_prefix2">Comments</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" id="submit">comment <i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var form_data = {
        body: $("#icon_prefix2").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>comments/create",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("msg");
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: What do you have in this JS function `comment()`? Also what is showing your console?

Comment: nothing is showing in the console. No errors after implementing RAUSHAN's answer.

Comment: there is no JS function comment()....

Comment: Check that in your submit button you are binding this onclick `onclick="comment()"` function

Comment: okay. I created the ajax function as an onclick function initially but I have removed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313247/there-are-some-unexpected-errors-in-form-validation-in-codeigniter-3/45313814#45313814

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `preventDefault()` function to prevent your form to be submitted

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form_data = {
       body: $("#icon_prefix2").val()
   };
   $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url();?>"+"comments/create",
       type: "POST",
       data: form_data,
       success: function(msg) {
           alert("msg");
       }
   });
   return true;
});
```

Comment: it is not submiting. the button just keeps getting clicked but no action

Comment: check the ajax url it is hitting

Comment: my controller is up there check it out because I used the correct url. "comments" is the controller name

Comment: hey man, ajax response you will get in console, check the console

Comment: I have checked the console

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it work

```
 $('#submit').click(function(event) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop actual action of browser
        var form_data = {
            body: $("#icon_prefix2").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>comments/create",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("msg");
            }
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Change button type `button` instead of `submit`

```
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" name="action" id="submit">comment
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
 </button>
```

Comment: This still reloads the whole page

Comment: @King i have update my answer please check and try like,

Answer (score 0):

Try the `done` property to set the success handler. Also, as this is an event over a DOM element, you should attach it when the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        var form_data = {
            body: $("#icon_prefix2").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>comments/create",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
        }).done(function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }).fail(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('ERROR: ' + textStatus);
        });

        // return is not necessary here
        // return true;
    });

    $("#comnt").submit(function(e) { // Prevent the form submitting
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

As this already attaches an event, you should remove the `onclick="comment()"` property from your button:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="submit">comment
                                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                              </button>
```

Comment: removed and still same thing. the comment does not get submitted and no message

Comment: it posts now but reloads the whole page.

Comment: @King added a new event that should prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: whole page still submits